# Append tweets one by one Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I got the following code to get the 4 newest tweets of a #.

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=4&callback=?&q=%23jQuery&result_type=recent' ,function(data){

    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++){
        var tweeter = data.results[i].from_user;
        var tweetText = data.results[i].text;
        var tweetText = tweetText.substring(0, 139);

        $(tweetCont).hide().append(
        '<div class="tweet"><p><span class="tweetName"><a href="http://twitter.com/' + tweeter + '">' + tweeter + '</a></span> '
        + tweetText + '<br /><span class="tweetTime">' + tweetTime(data.results[i].created_at) + '</span></p></div>'
        ).fadeIn('fast');
    }

});
```

When I'm appending the tweets they all fade in at the same time. I like to let them fade in one by one with a delay of lets say 500 milliseconds. A simple .delay(500) before the fadeIn('fast') won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar - let me know if it works:

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=4&callback=?&q=%23jQuery&result_type=recent' ,function(data){

    var which = 0;

for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++){
    var tweeter = data.results[i].from_user;
    var tweetText = data.results[i].text;
    var tweetText = tweetText.substring(0, 139);

    $(tweetCont).append(
    '<div class="tweet" style="display: none;"><p><span class="tweetName"><a href="http://twitter.com/' + tweeter + '">' + tweeter + '</a></span> '
    + tweetText + '<br /><span class="tweetTime">' + tweetTime(data.results[i].created_at) + '</span></p></div>'
    );

    if ( i == (data.results.length - 1) ) {
        showTweet();
    }
}



    function showTweet() {
        $(tweetCont).find('.tweet').eq(which).fadeIn('fast');
        which++;
                    if ( which < data.results.length ) {
        setTimeout(showTweet, 500);
                    }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are hiding and fading in the tweets container (`$(tweetCont)`).
You should probably append each tweet to the container and then fade in each tweet with a delay (produced with the help of `setTimeout`) :

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=4&callback=?&q=%23jQuery&result_type=recent' ,function(data){

    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++){
        var tweeter = data.results[i].from_user;
        var tweetText = data.results[i].text;
        var tweetText = tweetText.substring(0, 139);

        var tweetHtml = '<div class="tweet"><p><span class="tweetName"><a href="http://twitter.com/' + tweeter + '">' + tweeter + '</a></span> '
                    + tweetText + '<br /><span class="tweetTime">' + tweetTime(data.results[i].created_at) + '</span></p></div>';
        var $el =  $(tweetHtml)
                        .hide()
                        .appendTo(tweetCont);
        (function(el,index){
            setTimeout(function(){
               el.fadeIn('fast');
            },500 * index);
        })($el,i);
    }

});
```

Comment: They get appended but they don't fade in.

Comment: It seems like it don't get appended.

Comment: @timG Sorry, I accidentally replaced `tweetCont` with `tweetHtml`. See update.